# Cover page formatting

Tags: formatting, titles, titling

Could anyone help me out with making a cover page as shown in the picture? I am stuck with making the parts after the date. Thank you!

```
\title{ \normalsize \textsc{}
        \LARGE \textbf{{Electronics and Computer Science
Faculty of Engineering and Physical Sciences
University of Southampton}
        \normalsize \vspace*{5\baselineskip}}
        }


\author{
        Author \\
        }



\maketitle
```

[image]

Comment: The `titling` package might help.

Comment: @ZeyuXanthusWang Welcome to LaTeX-- have look at the answer below to see if it meets the requirement

Comment: @ZeyuXanthusWang would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

This could help you get closer to your requirement

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum }

\author{names}
\title{Project Title}
\date{text}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printcover}{%
        \begin{titlepage}
            \begin{center}
            \normalsize
                    Electronics and Computer Science \\Faculty of Engineering and Physical Sciences\\ University of Southampton 
                    
            \vfill 
            \@author
            \vfill          
            \@date          
            \vfill          
            {\bfseries\@title}
            \vfill          
            Project Supervisor: Supervisor          
            \vspace*{2em}
            
            Second Examiner: 2nd Examiner
            \vfill      
            A project progress report submitted for the award of
            
            Degree Title
            \end{center}
        \end{titlepage}
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%       \frontmatter
        \printcover
%       \mainmatter 
        \chapter{Introduction}
        \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```